# listIterator.hasNext() takes two presses to go to other item

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I found a bit of a bug in my application, this did not happen until today, and I have no clue how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
 Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);

        next.setEnabled(listIterator.hasNext());
        back.setEnabled(listIterator.hasNext());

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {




            public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.next()));
                        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                        videoView.start();


                        String text = String.valueOf(listIterator1.next());
                        textView4.setText(text);
                    }




            }
        });




        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {




            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.previous()));
                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoView.start();


                    String text = String.valueOf(listIterator1.previous());
                    textView4.setText(text);


                }


            }
        });
```

As you can see, i decalred two buttons, back and next, which I use for a series of video items I add into it. It was working fine for a few videos, but when the number of video increased suddenly it needed to be pressed two times. but not all the time. THis is what happens.

User presses, **next** it looks like it was nexted but it was just on the same item, and then he presses **next** again then it switches to another item for the next presses, no double happens. The but when the user presses **prev** it has to be pressed twice again. I think the list is iterating

1 1 2 3 4 5 6 **next**
**prev** 6 6 5 4 3 2 1

How do I fix this? I tried over and over and nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you display the first item?

Comment: I add it simply like this:       `final List listA = new ArrayList<>();
        listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.v1);`

Comment: This was not the question. How do you put the first video URL into the video view? In other words, has the `listIterater` already moved past the first item?

Comment: ohh sorry, I set it like this sir,       `Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.v1);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);`

Comment: It's because the first call to iterator.next() will return video 1, so the next button will still show video 1.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta for that part, I had set up the text of v1(the current without iterator) to be something. what Im confused of is  why its applying to other items in the list?